# Regression model for count data with an upper bound

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, count-data, bounds

What is an appropriate econometric model to describe count data with an upper bound?

Comment: Depends on why it has an upper bound: is it like a binomial?Describe your outcome!

Comment: You can write your Poisson or neg binomial likelihood for the outcomes that are observed with a step of 1, and for the censored outcomes as a sum over the remaining probabilities from the upper bound to infinity. It's probably 15 lines or so in Stata.

Comment: There's not enough information to guess; it might be binomial, or you may need some modification of some other kind of count variate... you'd need tp describe the nature of the variable and how the upper bound operates.

Answer (score 1):

You may assume that data above some threshold are censored and not observed, and using the censored count model will be a way to go.